# Using parallel capacitor-diode pairs to limit current in an AC circuit

Tags: ac, electrolytic-capacitor

I want to limit current from an AC source using capacitors.  As I am using dielectric (polar) capacitors, I thought I could use 2 capacitors with opposite polarity in parallel with a diode in front of each capacitor to protect it from reverse bias damage (see circuit diagram for clarification). My thinking was that every time the source's polarity switches, the current will go through a different capacitor-diode pair, always with the capacitor's reactance limiting the source's current.

When attempting to do this in practice, no current moves at all, so I must be misunderstanding something very important.  Would any kind sage be interested in pointing out my error?  I'm a physicist who likes to tinker, so if this is something embarrassingly stupid, that I should have learned in AC 101, I apologize. [image: Circuit Diagram]

I'm mostly interested in understanding the general idea of why this won't work, but if you'd like details, the AC source is mains (120VAC, 60Hz), the capacitors are 22uF, 400V, the diodes are 5A, 1000V rated.

Comment: How are the capacitors supposed to discharge?

Comment: And what's the load?

Comment: Ooops...  So then would there be a configuration that would both protect the capacitor and discharge it?

In this case the load is an AC heating element, but I was curious about general solutions.

Comment: Connect the capacitors in series, connecting both the positive wires together, or connecting both negatives together. Capacitance will half, voltage will increase some between 1.01 and 2 times depending on their quality and they will become unpolarised.

Comment: @Asmyldof: That will result in a stippled ceiling. Your arrangement will have half mains voltage across each capacitor. You need reverse polarity prodection. See my answer.

Comment: @Transistor You mean Cornell and Panasonic don't know how capacitors work? The only early morning mistake I made was of doubling voltage, that's only true for normal series operation. The reverse biased Alu Elec cap will leak all its charge into the forward biased one, making the ratio 1:1000 or even much less. No ceiling problems whatsoever.

Comment: @Asmyldof: That's news to me, but I'm always interested. Leaking charge means that current must be flowing through the electrolyte. That means heat. Too much heat usually means stippled ceiling. What specific Cornell and Panasonic capacitors are you referring to? Link to datasheet or reference explaining this mode of operation? Edit: I found a link on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/21928/can-you-make-a-non-polar-electrolytic-capacitor-out-of-two-regular-electrolytic. I'll have a read.

Comment: @Transistor The whole mechanism that causes explosion in reverse use in this case helps. The forward resistance is TOhms, where reverse resistance is very low in comparison. With a fixed voltage source that means high currents and noticeable heat, however, when paired with a forward biased one, that means many orders of magnitude more goes into charging the forward biased one, than go into heating the reverse one (4 to 6 orders in many cases). The forward one effectively limits the problems so much even long term use normally doesn't cause a very significant life reduction.

Comment: @Asmyldof: Thanks. The link in the other question was dead and Google says that's the only place it's available. I'd be interested in reading the application note.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm mostly interested in understanding the general idea of why this won't work ...

Because there is no discharge path once the capacitors are charged.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6MjVN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Rearranging the diodes provides a discharge path for the capacitors and reverse polarity protection.*

How it works:

- When L goes positive D1 is reverse biased and C1 charges. D2 prevents C2 being charged more than 0.7 to 1.0 V reverse.
- When L goes negative the reverse happens.

The effective capacitance will be the value of one of the capacitors since only one is in use at any time.

I used this arrangement almost 40 years ago to replace a failed starting capacitor on a family friend's 230 V well pump. (It died on a Friday evening on a bank-holiday weekend. How do capacitors know what day it is?) I used a couple of valve amplifier capacitors and suitable diodes. It worked but I was concerned about the long-term reliability due to the small reverse bias on each cycle so I replaced it with an unpolarised capacitor as soon as possible.

---

Update after comments.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQEsK9.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. Original redrawn with GND applied between the two capacitors to assist in visualisation with the simulation.*

[image]

*Figure 3. Results of simulation of Figure 2 when V1 is set to 100 V<sub>p-p</sub>.*

Comment: Thanks!  I'm curious as to why the standard solution seems to not include the diodes, as your circuit looks like it would result in the capacitors operating nearly identically to their intended specs, likely increasing lifetime.  Are the diodes left out just for bulk/cost reasons?

Comment: The following statement is wrong: *"The effective capacitance will be the value of one of the capacitors since only one is in use at any time."* While with the first cycle of the input voltage, the capacitors are uncharged and positive current only flows through C1 and D2 and negative current only flows through C2 and D1, both capacitors eventually will become charged and their + terminal will have a higher voltage than their - terminal. Thereby they reverse bias their parallel connected diodes and block current from flowing through them.

Comment: ... All current now has to flow through both capacitors, making the effective capacitance the half of one capacitor (if both of them are of same size).

Answer (score 3):

Here's what happens as time goes by...

[image]

For power applications, a capacitive dropper isn't always a good choice, but when it is it's far better to use a single film capacitor, as shown below, than to use a pair of electrolytics hooked in series opposition, as suggested earlier.

The reason for that is that the electrolytics will always dissipate more power in their electrolytes and dielectrics than the film caps will in their dielectrics, and the electrolytics will run hotter and vent their magic smoke sooner.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I was intending to change for 2 dielectric capacitors in series, but now I'll look into getting some film capacitors.

Comment: All capacitors depend on electrically insulating dielectrics to separate their plates and, as far as I know,  there's no such thing as a "dielectric capacitor".\

Answer (score 0):

Each C would conduct current during one half of the first cycle and then would be charged to the peak +/- voltage then stop conducting current.

Comment: Ya, thanks.  Ignacio pointed out the issue.  Any suggestion for a different setup with polar capacitors in an AC circuit?