# Vintage speaker capacitor ID

Tags: capacitor, identification

I would appreciate any help on identifying these capacitors I have inside a pair of vintage speakers. The speakers in the cabinets are EV and University Loudspeaker Inc so I know these are old timers. I wanted to clean them up and replace some wiring and possibly the two capacitors in each cabinet. I am new to this so I do not know how to ID old vintage electrical parts.

[image]

Here are some of the marking on them. "TM CAPACITOR" / Max Temp 85 deg C / Made In USA /600067  -2 / 232  642 / 857009 / MFD 4  VOLT 25 / NON POLARIZED

Comment: But didn't you just identify it yourself? It's a non polarized 4 MFD 25 V capacitor with 85 °C temperature rating, manufactured in USA by TM Capacitor. What other identification you need? Those kind of electrolytic caps are exactly what you would expect to find in a speaker.

Comment: When looking for a replacement note that MFD is an older marking style that has been replaced by uF.

Comment: You could get very close with parts you might already have on-hand by using two standard polarized 4.7uF 25V (or higher V rated) E-caps.   See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/21928/can-you-make-a-non-polar-electrolytic-capacitor-out-of-two-regular-electrolytic

Comment: A HUGE thank you to all who answered my question, obviously I am clueless about electronic parts so thank you , thank you, thank you to all who assisted me, you guys are awesome !!!